# How to alter table in Postgres to show Timestamp with Time Zone abbreviation (2004-10-19 10:23:54 EST)

Tags: postgresql, datetime, alter-table, alter, sql-timestamp

I want to alter my table row from 2011-06-30 05:59:59+00 format into 2011-06-30 05:59:59 CDT format

Comment: Postgres timestamps do not actually store timezone information.  Also realize that an offset from GMT in hours does not necessarily make it possible to figure out which _location_ that timezone is.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim told, postgres does not store `TZ` info. You can't change column this way. Unless you create function or view or something (which won't be changing the table anyway). What you do instead, you [change timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html) to see your needed:

> timezone (string)
>
> Sets the time zone for displaying and interpreting
>   time stamps. If not explicitly set, the server initializes this
>   variable to the time zone specified by its system environment. See
>   Section 8.5.3 for more information.

And use [formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html) to display `TZ` info... Like here:

```
b=# select now();
             now
-----------------------------
 2016-12-07 15:13:35.1369+00
(1 row)

b=# set timezone = EST;
SET

b=# select to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ');
         to_char
-------------------------
 2016-12-07 10:13:55 EST
(1 row)
```