# Postgresql stores timezone information in TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.4, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to understand how PostgreSQL handles TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE type, and I 'm running into the discrepancy between theory and practice.

According to the documentation and other stack overflow posts,

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC ...  When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone.

I believe this means that all timestamps in any given SELECT statement will be in the same/current timezone. However, this is what I see:
[image]

interview_timestamp is TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE. This blows my mind.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between timestamps with/without time zone in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql)

Comment: What does psql output?

Comment: This looks like a rendering bug in your client. The "-05:44:38" timezone is particularly suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that you sometimes see a time zone offset and sometimes not, I would blame that on the GUI you are using. Try with `psql` and see how the data look there.

The offset “-05:44:38” is perfectly normal, since [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) were introduced in the late 19th century and local solar time is used before that.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this was really a client thing and it because an offset from UTC depends on the time of year (EDT: -4, EST: -5). Offset "-05:44:38" is correct too, this is offset in TZ database for EDT/EST for years prior to 1883.