# Postgres: Get number of days since date

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with information about articles.  I have a `published_at` column that's a `timestamp without time zone` and want to calculate how long ago each article was published, in days.

So if it was published a week ago, I should get back `7`.

Any idea how to go about?

I know Postgres has `NOW()` but can I just subtract and then take `DAY()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can subtract one date from another, the result will be the number of days between the two dates. If one of them is a timestamp, just cast it to a date:

```
select current_date - published_at::date
from your_table;
```

If you want to get those that are younger then 7 days, you can use:

```
select current_date - published_at::date as age_in_days
from your_table
where published_at >= current_date - 7;
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use date_trunc, eg:

```
t=# select date_trunc('day',now() - '2016-01-01'::date);
 date_trunc
------------
 580 days
(1 row)
```

or for digit result, `extract`

```
t=# select extract('day' from date_trunc('day',now() - '2016-01-01'::date));
 date_part
-----------
       580
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use these slightly different versions.

```
SELECT
    NOW() - published_at, -- returns X days hh:mm:ss...
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW() - published_at), -- returns difference in days
    CURRENT_DATE - published_at -- returns difference in days
;
```

- more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql) for the potential effects of doing operations with/without timestamps
- an old [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/48B1BE33.3060505%40vieonet.com) reporting the potential performance impacts of `NOW()` vs `CURRENT_DATE`