# How can I change type of a column in Postgres while using sqoop import to hdfs?

Tags: postgresql, hdfs, sqoop

I have a column in Postgres database with a type timestamp without timezone. How do I convert it into timestamp with timezone(UTC) while importing into hdfs using sqoop?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the query rather than table in your sqoop import statement.

```
 sqoop import --connect xxx,DATABASE=xxx
 ---driver xxx --username xxx --password xxx 
 --query 'select * from xxx' 
 --target-dir <hdfs-location> ...
```

Here is how you can convert from timestamp without timezone to timezone(UTC)

```
SELECT '2011-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
```

You can refer this link : [Difference between timestamps with/without time zone in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql)