# Timestamp Comparison within Function

Tags: postgresql, timezone

To prevent older version overwrite new version, in this simple function:

```
create function myupdate(paramts timestamp without time zone, ...)
  language plpgsql AS
$$
begin
-- step 1 compare current record timestamp vs. supplied timestamp
if exists (select 1 from record where ts <> paramts and ...) then
    raise exception 'A newer version exists, cannot update.';
end if;
...
end
$$;
```

`ts` definition is the same `timestamp without time zone`.

`paramts` value is supplied by a function:

```
create function myfetch(...)
  language plpgsql AS
$$
begin
    return query select ts, ... from record where ...;
end
$$;
```

What node API and Angular client UI gets is **2021-04-16T21:37:35.878Z** so is the value submitted to `myupdate()`. However, at one of our West Coast server, during execution inside of `myupdate()`, `ts` is auto-converted to PST **2021-04-16 14:37:35.878694** and has 3 extra digits at right.

How to compare both in UTC and same precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`)** instead of `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`) to avoid any time zone confusion. In the table, in the function, in the whole food chain. Values are always stored as UTC time internally then, and comparisons work correctly automatically (comparing points in time independent of time zones).

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Either way, both types have *microsecond* resolution, i.e. ***6*** factional decimal digits. Your first example got truncated somehow, possibly by your client in the display.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the suggestion, even though the Answer doesn't answer all my question, I still accept it because `tz` is the best solution. I'll post my complete Answer and Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Answer:

1. Use `tz` = Timestamp **`with`** time zone for column definition.
2. `tz` always feeds clients with UTC values, for example I'm using node/pg-promise, frontend is Angular/TS, they all get value like `2021-04-17T22:42:57.610Z`.
3. UTC out, UTC submitted back (assuming you don't touch timestamp), is it good enough? Yes and No. Yes if your client supports **6-digits** decimal second otherwise No for JavaScript and variants as it supports only 3-digits.
4. Solution is to round to 2-digits then compare

`if (select tableTimestamp::timestamp(2) = parameter::timestamp(2) from mytable where ...) then  Update mytable ...; else raise exception ...; end if;`

P.S., `with` and `without time zone` is confusing.