# .NET6 and DateTime problem. Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, npgsql

I have common problem.

> Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp
> without time zone'

And I want to enable Legacy Timestamp behavoour as is documented here:
https://github.com/npgsql/doc/blob/main/conceptual/Npgsql/types/datetime.md/

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> contextOptions) : base(contextOptions)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions", true);
        }
```

But doesn't work. I still get same error.

What I am doing wrong. Why legacy behaviour doesn't work?

Comment: You'll have to share some code that shows what you're doing, as well as the full exception with the stack trace.

Comment: breaking changes https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2000

Comment: @NickKovalsky The "breaking change" mentions " 'Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone'," which makes sense, while the current error mentions Kind=UTC. IMO the error message mentioned in this question is very confusing since it suggests that the date is already of Kind.UTC. I have also stumbled across this error while feeding SaveChanges with Kind.UTC does not make sense (I expect it should be able to persist UTC date in timestamps without time zone).

Comment: I feel neccessary to add comment about "why" exactly this behaviour was implemented the way it was - it's because Postgresql doesn't actually store timezone even in "timestamp with timezone" type - it just assumes that input time is in UTC.

So it's really easy to "shoot off your leg" in this one, especially when you use something like DateTime.Now

More on that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql

Answer (score 141):

**A**. Solved by adding

`AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);`
to the `Startup` `Configure` method.

---

**B**. Or in case you have no Startup class at all and all your initialization is inside Program.cs with a host builder then your file ending might look like:

```
... //adding services etc
var host = builder.Build();
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
... //your other scoped code
await host.RunAsync();
```

---

To query database using `System.Linq.Dynamic` we need to specify time kind too.
Filter example:
`$"User.BirthDate>={time.ToStringUtc()}"`

```
public static string ToStringUtc(this DateTime time)
{
    return $"DateTime({time.Ticks}, DateTimeKind.Utc)";
}
```

---

At the same time the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70142836/7149454 by @istvan-kardkovacs applies. Basically to add an .`SetKindUtc()` to every `= new DateTime()` you are creating.. The switch above didn't obviously worked for me in a background hosted service that was populating database before any other code was executed.

Comment: when switched to .net 6 (from core 3.1) i got this error and this is simplest way to solve it

Comment: Ran into this with a .net6 application and a PostgreSQL database. Added option B to my startup and fixed it.

Comment: If you're using NHibernate I would suggest using Npgsql below version 6 (since NHibernate hasn't implemented the correct mapping yet => https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2994)

Answer (score 31):

You have to set the DateTimeKind for all DateTime fields in the create,insert,update operations and for the DateTime comparisons in the Linq queries.
I have created a small extension method and add to all date fields.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? SetKindUtc(this DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime.HasValue)
        {
            return dateTime.Value.SetKindUtc();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static DateTime SetKindUtc(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc) { return dateTime; }
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

And unit-tests to show functionality:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyNamespace;

[TestClass]
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class DateTimeExtensionsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetKindUtcNullInputTest()
    {
        DateTime? input = null;
        DateTime? result = input.SetKindUtc();
        Assert.IsNull(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SetKindUtcNonNullRegularDateInputTest()
    {
        DateTime? input = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime? result = input.SetKindUtc();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        /* below is the primary functionality.  if the input did not have a "Kind" set, it gets set to DateTimeKind.Utc */
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, result.Value.Kind);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SetKindUtcNonNullOffsetDateInputTest()
    {
        DateTime? input = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime withKindUtcInput = DateTime.SpecifyKind(input.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime? result = withKindUtcInput.SetKindUtc();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        /* Utc "in" remains "Utc" out */
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, result.Value.Kind);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnspecifiedKindIsOverwrittenTest()
    {
        DateTime? input = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime withKindUtcInput = DateTime.SpecifyKind(input.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        DateTime? result = withKindUtcInput.SetKindUtc();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        /* note the behavior.  "DateTimeKind.Unspecified" with overwritten with DateTimeKind.Utc */
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, result.Value.Kind);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void LocalKindIsOverwrittenTest()
    {
        DateTime? input = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime withKindUtcInput = DateTime.SpecifyKind(input.Value, DateTimeKind.Local);
        DateTime? result = withKindUtcInput.SetKindUtc();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        /* note the behavior.  "DateTimeKind.Local" with overwritten with DateTimeKind.Utc */
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, result.Value.Kind);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Good place to put the setting is the static constructor of the DB Context.

In this case startup class remains cleaner.
Also it's useful if you have several projects using the same DB Context.
E.g:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    }
    
    // Other stuff of your context
}
```

### Update July 2023 - Solution #2

Today I've faced with an issue when this trick didn't work in one of my projects.
After researching I found another way to make sure the flag can be set once before any other code runs.

It's done with help of [ModuleInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/general#moduleinitializer-attribute) attribute:

**Note:** it requires **C#9** and higher (**.NET 5+**)

Just add a new file to your project where DbContext is located.
And put next content:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Your.Project.Namespace;

public static class MyModuleInitializer
{
    [ModuleInitializer]
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: we tried this but we still get same exception as below.
Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Local to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', with particular context Kinds in an array/range.

Comment: @Dreamer, I've updated an answer with 2nd solution, hope it will help you as it helped me.

Comment: Update July 2023 fixed the problem for me. It looks like the 1st solution stopped working as I had it implemented

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was a mistake I made

```
InvitedOn = DateTime.Now
```

should have been

```
InvitedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
```

and it worked

Comment: Comment has -1 to it. Can anyone explain exactly why? Is this bad approach in general or  simply because it's impractical for already existing/legacy programs?

Comment: Probably because it doesn't explain anything and a bit out of context?  In general, its better to use UtcNow,(short answer) gets rid of all issues with timezones.
But i got the same error, and this fixed it. Hopefully it might help someone else

Comment: @DanielPace why do you consider UtcNow a "better to use" approach? with a huge number of local apps storing local DateTime might be preferred vs UTC and convert it back all the time. Better to use because some Microsoft employee said it is? Or because Shay R. (the library maintainer) said it? Since EF provides an abstraction layer one shouldn't treat Postgres target differently from say MS-SQL. For years using DateTimeOffset would result in "automatic" conversion to UTC but suddenly all broke, and we have to branch out DateTimeOffset assignments in application code when targeting Postgres?!

Comment: I think the problem is that Postgres does not handle timezones, so EF might not be able to abstract that bit for you (missing data). But that problem aside. You should use UTC because its simpler for lots of reasons and scenarios that i cant explain in this comment box. I'm also not the best person to explain why, im sure many others already did.
But to keep it simple, your users can travel across different timezones, and the UI/app should handle that. You might also want to query the DB and filter based on time, MSSQL might handle that(I dont know) but other DB's might not.

Answer (score 15):

Nick has already answered this question, I just want to add another solution to this time zone problem.

Instead of enabling that option, you can just convert all datetime before being written using this extension. This is what I did.

Create this extension class:

```
public static class UtcDateAnnotation
{
    private const string IsUtcAnnotation = "IsUtc";
    private static readonly ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime> UtcConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(convertTo => DateTime.SpecifyKind(convertTo, DateTimeKind.Utc), convertFrom => convertFrom);

    public static PropertyBuilder<TProperty> IsUtc<TProperty>(this PropertyBuilder<TProperty> builder, bool isUtc = true) => builder.HasAnnotation(IsUtcAnnotation, isUtc);

    public static bool IsUtc(this IMutableProperty property)
    {
        if (property != null && property.PropertyInfo != null)
        {
            var attribute = property.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<IsUtcAttribute>();
            if (attribute is not null && attribute.IsUtc)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return ((bool?)property.FindAnnotation(IsUtcAnnotation)?.Value) ?? true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make sure this is called after configuring all your entities.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ApplyUtcDateTimeConverter(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (!property.IsUtc())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) ||
                    property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    property.SetValueConverter(UtcConverter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class IsUtcAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IsUtcAttribute(bool isUtc = true) => this.IsUtc = isUtc;
    public bool IsUtc { get; }
}
```

And add that converter in your DbContext file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     builder.ApplyUtcDateTimeConverter();//Put before seed data and after model creation
}
```

This will result all your DateTime and DateTime? object got converted to Utc kind of date before being written to Db.

This will be my one way ticket to support this PostgreSql Db, because I have a requirement to support some database (Sql Server, PostgreSql, and soon MySql). Manually convert every datetime value to Utc won't be a good solution.

Our application hasn't had requirement for time zone yet, but using that extension we could easily add time zone support in it.

Comment: It works! I think is the best proposed solution for legacy projects.

Comment: It is a very elegant solution. I am looking into applying the same principle with NHibernate for my legacy System.DateTime mappings. Thinking about following the recommended Nodatime for dealing with date, time and instant types using npgsql for new entities.

Comment: .net has DatetimeOffset that will store UTC information. I learned that we could use that, but I haven't got a change to test that.

Answer (score 6):

I added code to my `DbContext` to set this on all date properties on my models:

```
//dbcontext
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    _changeTrackerManager?.FixupEntities(this);
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

//don't forget the async method!
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    _changeTrackerManager?.FixupEntities(this);
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This `IChangeTrackerManager` dependency will be injected, and then any time entities are saved it will call this method below which will fixup all the utc date time kinds.

```
public void FixupEntities(DbContext context)
{
    var dateProperties = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
        .Select(z => new
        {
            ParentName = z.DeclaringEntityType.Name,
            PropertyName = z.Name
        });

    var editedEntitiesInTheDbContextGraph = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .Select(x => x.Entity);

    foreach (var entity in editedEntitiesInTheDbContextGraph)
    {
        var entityFields = dateProperties.Where(d => d.ParentName == entity.GetType().FullName);

        foreach (var property in entityFields)
        {
            var prop = entity.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName);

            if (prop == null)
                continue;

            var originalValue = prop.GetValue(entity) as DateTime?;
            if (originalValue == null)
                continue;

            prop.SetValue(entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind(originalValue.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a little bit late, but for me I just created this converter

```
public class DateTimeToDateTimeUtc : ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>
{
    public DateTimeToDateTimeUtc() : base(c => DateTime.SpecifyKind(c, DateTimeKind.Utc), c => c)
    {

    }
}
 protected sealed override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
            .HaveConversion(typeof(DateTimeToDateTimeUtc));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also stumbled across this error while trying to persist a DateTime with Kind = UTC (I am actually using `DateTime.UtcNow`) in a "timestamp without time zone" column. IMO, the error does not make sense, since UTC datetimes should be without timezone.

My fix was to switch to "timestamp with time zone" because:

- it seems to work as expected: I get the {UTC timestamp}+00
- "EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior" sounds like something that is likely to be deprecated in the future
- Converting all DateTime's to UTC Kind while elegant sounds like a hack that might backfire in some scenarios where I really want some DateTime of another Kind

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and to solve this, I used DateTime.ToUniversalTime() Method in C#.

For example,

```
Date= DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

Or,

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

To obtain more detail, you can browse this site
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/datetime-touniversaltime-method-in-c-sharp/

Comment: I used this method but, When I store my date in Postresql date is with timezone

Answer (score 2):

modifying https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179214/507421 from @DLeh slightly

```
    private void ConvertDateTimesToUniversalTime()
    {
        var modifiedEntites = ChangeTracker.Entries<IHaveAggregateRootId>()
                .Where(e => (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted)).ToList();
        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntites)
        {
            foreach (var prop in entry.Properties)
            {
                if (prop.Metadata.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    prop.Metadata.FieldInfo.SetValue(entry.Entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)prop.CurrentValue, DateTimeKind.Utc));
                }
                else if (prop.Metadata.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?) && prop.CurrentValue != null)
                {
                    prop.Metadata.FieldInfo.SetValue(entry.Entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind(((DateTime?)prop.CurrentValue).Value, DateTimeKind.Utc));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I have updated the proyect with dotnet ef migrations add

Command reference:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <MigrationName> --context <YoutContextClassName> --startup-project <../Path to your startup proyect> --verbose
```

After it postgre have created the migration file changing all datetime from "with time zone" to "without time zone"

I hope It was usefull for you

**NOTA:**

- I've Updated from net5.0 to net6.0
- postgresql 6.0.X
- Using code-first to database.

**UPDATE**:

Also or after that you need to check Kind of DateTime if not is Utc you can force It with static SpecifyKind method of DateTime

[image]

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me when my Controller deserialize the object and I was trying to insert/update it with EF and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. I used ToUniversalTime() to all dates and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late with this but this is how I usually handle this:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)MyNullableDateTimeField!, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer. Don't add the lines to your dB Context. Instead in a WFP application add to  MainWindow.xaml.cs as follows:

add the line "EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior" before the
InitializeComponent statement in the public MainWindow method.

You don't need the "DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions" statement.

Your code with DateTime will now work.