# npgsql: Different treatment of seemingly same new DateTime construct

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

This is not duplicate of [.NET6 and DateTime problem. Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961449/net6-and-datetime-problem-cannot-write-datetime-with-kind-utc-to-postgresql-ty)

My code works

```cs
var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

var membershipPayments = from p in _context.Payments
                         ... joins ...
                         select new Payment
                         {
                             ...
                             PayableDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1),
                             ...
                         };
_context.AddRange(membershipPayments);
```

If I replace `PayableDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1),` with `PayableDate = new DateTime(currentYear, 1, 1),` code fails with messages

> Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Local to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

PayableDate type is 'timestamp without timezone' and I am not mixing anything. Trying to set kind in new DateTime to UTC just reverts the message: I cannot save UTC in 'timestamp without timezone'.

Is this a bug in npgsql or is there a subtle difference in DateTime construction

- `new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)` vs
- `new DateTime(currentYear, 1, 1)`

that I do not see?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, you'll have to submit an actual repro rather than a fragment, a minimal console program should do it (that's always a good idea when submitting questions/issues).