# Have a DateTime Kind.Unspecified column in Postgresql in EF Core

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have this database column:

```
[MaxLength(10)]
[Required]
public List<NpgsqlRange<System.DateTime>> Dates { get; set; }
```

How do I make this allow only Kind.Unspecified?

I get this error when I insert:

> System.InvalidCastException : Cannot write DateTime with
> Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only
> UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with
> different Kinds in an array/range. See the
> Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable
> legacy behavior.

Every single solution I have seen is to [use Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304966/3935156). However, that is to allow unspecified type in a UTC column, and I don't want to allow unspecified type in a UTC column. I want the column to be strongly typed as unspecified.

Also, when I use `EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior`, it saves it to postgresql with the "+12" in it, which IS UTC (which I don't want).

Comment: What is your field type in DB?

Comment: @Orifjon `Dates = table.Column<List<NpgsqlRange<System.DateTime>>>(type: "tstzmultirange", maxLength: 10, nullable: true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, your database type does not match your code type here. Database type `timestamp without time zone` corresponds to `DateTime(Kind=Unspecified)` and `timestamp with time zone` corresponds to `DateTime(Kind=UTC)`. for range and multirange types, these valuers cannot be mixed.

If you want to keep C# type, you can change
`Dates = table.Column<List<NpgsqlRange<System.DateTime>>>(type: "tstzmultirange", maxLength: 10, nullable: true)` to `Dates = table.Column<List<NpgsqlRange<System.DateTime>>>(type: "tsmultirange", maxLength: 10, nullable: true)`

Since you can get different kind of `DateTime`, you can explicitly create new `DateTime` instance with `Kind=Unspecified` before assigning it to `Dates` property.

For more details, See: [Type mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html)

[Postgresql built in types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN)

p.s.: You can also use `NodaTime` which aligns better with Postgresql types.

Comment: Thanks. That code I commented was generated. How do I change what is generated? The code in the question is the only place I defined the type.

Comment: It is generated based on your actual database type. If you can't change database type, you have to go with `DateTime(Kind=UTC)`.