# How does SQLAlchemy store datetime objects?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, timestamp

I have a PostgreSQL database that used to store timestamps without a timezone (`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` type). The ORM definition of the table looked something like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class TimeStampTable(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'timestamp'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # According to documentation DateTime is converted to naive timestamp 
    example_timestamp = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

I wanted to change the type of the column to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` to keep timezone information that was sent by my frontend.

The code for inserting the timestamp sent from the frontend looks something like this:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # Normally fetched from the request but the value comes as string WITH offset
    dt = datetime.strptime('2023-04-10T17:32:55+0200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    new_entry = TimeStampTable(example_timestamp=dt)

    db.session.add(new_entry)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'SUCCESS'
```

After changing my model it looked like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class TimeStampTable(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'timestamp'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    example_timestamp = mapped_column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

Which was giving me the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` type in my database. Up to this point everything seemed fine. But after investigating on the stored values in the database I became a bit confused.

In my mind (as outlined in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069726/20321717)) I thought Postgres would take the DateTime and just strip the offset. So in the example the value inserted to the database would be `2023-04-10 17:32:55`.

But it seems that SQLAlchemy is applying the offset first and then inserts the datetime object. So in this case if the database uses UTC the resulting database entry is `2023-04-10 15:32:55`.

After migrating to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` the process of inserting the values to the database remained exactly the same. SQLAlchemy takes the datetime, applies the offset and saves the datetime like `2023-04-10 15:32:55+00`.

*My question now is:*
What is the whole purpose of storing a value as datetime with timezone apart from getting a datetime with `tzinfo` out of the database if the functionality is exactly the same anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is not a function of SQLAlchemy *per se*, it is the behaviour of the DBAPI layer. We can reproduce the issue using just psycopg2:

```py
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

import psycopg2

cnxn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="192.168.0.199", user="scott", password="tiger", dbname="test"
)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

tablename = "timestamp"

crsr.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {tablename}")
crsr.execute(
    f"""\
CREATE TABLE {tablename} (
id int primary key,
description varchar(50),
ts_no_tz timestamp,
ts_with_tz timestamptz
)
"""
)

midnight_toronto = datetime.datetime(
    2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-5))
)

crsr.execute(
    f"INSERT INTO {tablename} (id, description, ts_no_tz, ts_with_tz) "
    "VALUES (%(id)s, %(description)s, %(ts_value)s, %(ts_value)s)",
    dict(id=1, description="aware_datetime", ts_value=midnight_toronto),
)
crsr.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE id = 1")
pprint(crsr.fetchone())
"""
(1,
 'aware_datetime',
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
"""
```

We see that psycopg2 has recognized the tz-aware datetime and adjusted the value stored into `ts_no_tz` by 5 hours. Both values returned have hour=5.

However, if we pass the datetime values as strings

```py
midnight_toronto_str = str(midnight_toronto)
print(midnight_toronto_str)  # 2001-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
crsr.execute(
    f"INSERT INTO {tablename} (id, description, ts_no_tz, ts_with_tz) "
    "VALUES (%(id)s, %(description)s, %(ts_value)s, %(ts_value)s)",
    dict(id=2, description="aware_string", ts_value=midnight_toronto_str),
)
crsr.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE id = 2")
pprint(crsr.fetchone())
"""
(2,
 'aware_string',
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
"""
```

the offset `-05:00` is simply ignored by the server for `ts_no_tz` and it has hour=0, not hour=5.

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely forgot that it is not SQLAlchemy that accesses the DB but psycopg2.