# Is this expected behavior for Python Datetime with timezone inserted into Postgres DB using sqlalchemy orm? What's going on?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, python-datetime

## Summary

Inserting datetime with timezone object into postgres column without timezone appears to first convert to a local timestamp and then removes the offset. Eg for 2024-01-15 19:04:38.921936+00:00 I expected to see 2024-01-15 19:04:38.92193 in the database, but we get: 2024-01-15 14:04:38.921936. (I'm in UTC-05)

## Some Context

In updating a bunch of a code base to Python 3.12, `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` calls that return a naive datetime object with UTC time were replaced with timezone aware datetime objects in UTC timezone - as recommended in the Python documentation (utcnow is soon to be deprecated). Using `sqlalchemy` 2.0.25 in python 3.12 on windows with Postgres 14 - I noticed some behavior I didn't expect, and I'm wondering if it's expected or not, and either way if someone with a better understanding can help me understand what's happening.

## The Behavior

Assume that you have a postgres database and a table with two columns:

- a col of type `timestamp without timezone` - which is the default type of column created by `sqlalchemy` with `psycopg2` drivers for sqlalchemy column type `Datetime`
- a col of type `timestamp with timezone` - which is the default type of column created by `sqlalchemy` with `psycopg2` driver for sqlalchemy column type `Datetime(timezone=True)`

Now insert two rows using the ORM:

- a python naive datetime.datetime object into both cols
- a python datetime.datetime object with timezone (UTC) into both cols

The result for the first row, or the naive datetime object, is that both timestamps are the same. This is what I expect, and this also what happens using SQLite instead of postgres.

Behavior for the second row, where the UTC timezone datetime object is inserted, is different. The postgres `timestamp with timezone` column is mostly as expected, it is displayed in local time instead of UTC time, but it has the correct UTC offset associated with it so it's referring to the same time and there's no real problem. Eg instead of `2024-01-15 19:04:38.921936+00:00` it shows `2024-01-15 14:04:38.921936-05:00` in my case.

On the other hand the postgres `timestamp without timezone` column in this case contains a timestamp with no timezone as expected, but it has been converted to local time. So it's as if the UTC timezone datetime object was first taken as the local time with timezone indicator (-XY:00), but then had the indicator striped to fit in the column (because it doesn't allow timezones).

That second part is what I didn't expect and actually caused some problems during the update. I expected it to take the timestamp, and just strip the timezone information. Eg if you print the datetime w/ timezone object, it prints relative to the timezone offset it was created with (eg for `2024-01-15 19:04:38.921936+00:00` I expected to see `2024-01-15 19:04:38.92193` in the database, but we get: `2024-01-15 14:04:38.921936`).

This is different from what happens with SQLite and the same setup - but I realize that might be a difference in how SQLite's timestamp columns work (I'm not familiar with that at the moment). At least the behavior in SQL is what I intuitively expected.

## Example

I set up a minimal test to show what I mean here: https://gist.github.com/heathhenley/35c89bbbc2fe6013e32e7e25ded5da0c
It might a little large to paste all in this question, but if that's preferred no problem.

It assumes you have a local postgres running with a "test_db" database (could use docker to spin up quickly), and pip installed sqlalchemy and psycopg2.

Example output from the test:

```
Testing sqlite
ts_now_with_tz: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044+00:00
ts_now_niave: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044
 Insert ts utc with tz -->  TS no TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044, TS with TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044
 Insert ts utc naive -->  TS no TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044, TS with TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.711044

Testing postgres
ts_now_with_tz: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.851948+00:00
ts_now_niave: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.851948
 Insert ts utc with tz -->  TS no TZ: 2024-01-15 14:11:06.851948, TS with TZ: 2024-01-15 14:11:06.851948-05:00
 Insert ts utc naive -->  TS no TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.851948, TS with TZ: 2024-01-15 19:11:06.851948-05:00
```

Please let me know if there is more information needed, would just like to understand it better if possible.

Basically all times we work with on the back end are always in UTC - so at the moment we're using columns of type `timestamp without timezone` as they're all UTC. Maybe in the future it's better to using timestamp with timezone, but I'll have to look into that.

Of course I can convert any datetime objects to UTC and strip timezone info to fix this problem. In that case the UTC timestamp ends up in the col - and this basically replicates the pre 3.12 version as all the datetimes were naive (but technically in UTC timezone). I would just like understand what's going on better if possible.

Is this expected behavior and why?

EDIT: Turned on "echo" - this is what gets emitted:

```
2024-01-15 15:37:12,239 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00006s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)]
{
  'timestamp_no_tz__0': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 15, 20, 37, 12, 238691, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
  'timestamp_with_tz__0': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 15, 20, 37, 12, 238691, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
  'note__0': 'Insert ts utc with tz',
  'timestamp_no_tz__1': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 15, 20, 37, 12, 238691),
  'timestamp_with_tz__1': datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 15, 20, 37, 12, 238691),
  'note__1': 'Insert ts utc naive'
}
2024-01-15 15:37:12,243 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: (Changed my mind and I agree this is not what I would be expected). This question seems to relate to the same behaviour by psycopg2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76235188/how-does-sqlalchemy-store-datetime-objects

Comment: Ah yes good find, yes that seems to be the same issue. I didn't think that it might be in psycopg2, so I must have missed it my searching. Perhaps I should try opening an issue with psycopg2 to see if this is expected?

Comment: It's not what I expected intuitively but maybe it's intended, it's not clear to me from the linked answer (probably skill issue)

Comment: It's interesting. The behaviour in that specific question seems reasonable, i.e. 00:00-05:00 (with the -05:00 explicitly in the datetime object) ends up being stored as 05:00.  But in your example, the 5-hour shift seems to be inferred from the system timezone, ignoring the explicit timezone.

Comment: What time zone is your PostgreSQL server using? `show timezone;` might give you a clue. (My other answer — cited above — failed to mention that the PostgreSQL server is using the UTC time zone.)

Comment: The postgres server is in UTC-5, it's not clear to me why that would cause it to get converted though, as it's going into a timestamp without timezone column.

Comment: To clarify, the PG server's actual timezone is UTC-5 (America/New York) - all the timestamps that we store though are stored as timestamps without timezone, and they are always in UTC time. It was never a problem until the switch python datetimes from naive datetimes with a UTC time to timezone aware datetimes in UTC timezone.

Comment: Ok so setting the time zone to "Etc/UTC" does give expected results. So I guess that means that postgres is looking at the incoming datetime with time zone, and correcting it to the timezone of the database before stripping the time zone and storing in the `timestamp without time zone`. I guess that's probably expected behavior, but I really expected that it would just ignore timezone info in the python datetime.

Comment: `show timezone; US/Pacific` then `select now()::timestamp;2024-01-15 12:57:57.989619`, then `set timezone = 'UTC';` then `select now()::timestamp;2024-01-15 21:01:31.253292`. For why see [Time Zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html): *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*.

Comment: Alright cool - so incoming naive datetime --> just store because there's no way to convert. Incoming datetime with time zone --> convert to server local time zone before stripping time zone info.

Answer (score 0):

As many have helped me see in the comments of the question, this is intended behavior for postgres. I guess the python datetime object with time zone is interpreted as a `timestamp with time zone` and then casted to a `timestamp without time zone` on insertion. As part of that cast, it is converted to the server's time zone.

I appreciate all the help!